# How to store data into global variables in x86 real mode ISR?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am developing INT 13H disk service routine of option rom(expansion rom) running in x86 real mode.
I need to access the global variables located at DS(DS=CS) while the routine is executing, but the global variables become read-only! 
Only local variables located at SS(SS!=DS) can be accessed normally, but the size of stack is not enough. 
The size I need is about 2KB in the routine. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to store data into global variables in the routine?
2. How to find/locate 2KB usable memory in the routine?

Thanks a lot.

```
int global_var;

void __far int13h_isr(void)
{
    int local_var;

    __asm
    {
        push    ds
        push    es
        mov     bx, cs
        mov     ds, bx
        mov     es, bx
    };


    global_var = 0x22;  // global variable can NOT store 0x22 in the routine. 
    local_var  = 0x22;  // local variable can store 0x22 correctly.

    __asm
    {
        pop es
        pop ds
    };    
}
```

Comment: What does "can NOT" mean here? You cannot? You get a compile or runtime error? Are you sure you can mix C and assembly like this? Did you check the produced assembler code?

Comment: @usr2564301: The memory access goes somewhere else.

Comment: You need to post an [mcve] to get debugging help here. You need include all of the code that reproduces the problem in your question itself, the steps you took to build the code, how you ran the code, what behaviour you expected and what behaviour you actually got.

Comment: It is weird that a global variable suddenly becomes read-only. But as you change the value of DS in an asm block, it could have a value different from what the compiler would expect. What is the memory model? Or if you prefere is `global_var` *far* or *near*?

Comment: @RossRidge: if it is a problem of real mode segments in a 16 bits memory model, a [mcve] would only make sense if build in the same memory model

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write the whole ISR in pure asm?  Then you don't have to worry about getting the compiler to save/restore stuff differently from what it might do for a normal function call.  Or maybe write an asm wrapper that sets up some sane segment registers before calling a C function.  Using inline asm to mess with segment registers just seems like a bad idea / making life difficult compared to using a `far` attribute on a variable or pointer and having the compiler do it.  (Look at the compiler output to see if it's making the asm you want.)

Comment: @PeterCordes tI would be easier to use assembly, no one writes disk controller option ROMs in any other language, but I'm guessing the original poster here doesn't know assembly very well and thinks they can get around that problem by using C. But the problems here are profound, using the small memory model but assuming CS = DS, assuming an option ROM would be writable, needing 2K of RAM that simply isn't available to option ROMs, confusing option ROMs with TSRs, etc..

Comment: You can't write TSRs that aren't tiny memory model. The system call for creating a TSR doesn't support it. And sorry, I have no documentation for OpenWatcom.

Answer (score 0):

> INT 13H disk service routine of option rom(expansion rom)
>   Is it possible to store data into global variables in the routine?

Data can't be stored into ROM. The expansion card would need it's own memory if the memory is needed before a device driver can be loaded.

> How to find/locate 2KB usable memory in the routine?

A device driver along with it's ISR can allocate memory, but MSDOS or some other operating system would have to be able to boot and load the device driver before using any expansion specific INT 13H calls.

Comment: To rcgldr:
1. could you teach me or give a direction how to locate 2KB safe RAM in the ISR? 
2. I'm not quite understand that "MSDOS or some other operating system would have to be able to boot and load the device driver before using any expansion specific INT 13H calls". Do you mean I shouldn't locate memory in the ISR?

Comment: @marky1 - Using MSDOS as an example, if a device driver is loaded (usually during config.sys), then to retain "safe ram", it just needs to include that ram as part of it's image when it exits via INT 21H, AX = 03100H, DX = address of end of driver, which leaves the driver in memory. As noted in my answer, until the device driver is loaded, then any expansion specific calls that need the 2K of ram could not be used.